# Hovering betweend images, box shadow CSS only

Tags: html, css, css-grid, box-shadow

I have partially stacked two images using CSS Grid. The image that the user hovers over increases in `z-index` and therefore overlays the other. Users can switch back and forth between those two images.

Now I am wondering if it's possible to give the image that it is currently in "focus"/has the higher `z-index` a `box-shadow` that appears/disappears, depending which image is on top. Is that even possible using CSS only?

Example of what I mean. And the grey layer seems to have a shadow.
http://vrscigroup.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can't achieve this with CSS only, you need something that tells CSS which is the card with the higher z-index, after that you can apply a class.

I would add something with js (jquery maybe?) that adds a class and use that class to add the box shadow, something like this:

```
$('.cards').hover(function() {
   // remove it from all cards
   $('.cards').removeClass('box-shadow');
   // add it to the one on hover only
   $(this).addClass('box-shadow');
});
```

After that just add the css class:

```
.cards.box-shadow {
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px #000;
}
```

Of course, that's just an example :)

Answer (score -1):

Use `:hover` pseudoclass here instead of JavaScript. Demo:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100px);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(3, 100px);
}

/* overlapping grid items */
.item-1 {
  grid-row: 1 / 3;
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  background-color: green;
}

.item-2 {
  grid-row: 2 / 4;
  grid-column: 2 / 4;
  background-color: yellow;
}

/* setting higher z-index on hover */
.item-1:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}

/* adding box shadow */
.item:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="item item-1"></div>
  <div class="item item-2"></div>
</div>
```